# Universal property of additive categories

Tags: category-theory, additive-categories

Keep in mind that I suck at cateogory theory, so please be gentle.

The definition of additive categeory that I have is that it is a preadditive category $\mathcal{C}$ with an object $0$ such that End$(0)$ is the trivial group and if finite direct sums exist. The existence of finite direct sums means the following: for a finite set $\left\{X_i\right\}_{i \in I}$ of objects in $\mathcal{C}$ there exists an object $\bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i$ and morphisms $j_k: X_k \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i(k \in I)$ satisfying the following universal property: if $Y \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $f_k \in \operatorname{Hom}\left(X_k, Y\right)(k \in I)$ then there exists a unique $f \in \operatorname{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i, Y\right)$ such that $f \circ j_k=f_k$ for all $k \in I$.

Now I want to prove that such this direct sum is unique up to isomorphism. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an additive category and $\left\{X_i\right\}_{i \in I}$ a finite set of objects. Suppose that $Z \in \operatorname{Ob}(\mathcal{O})$ and $i_k \in \operatorname{Hom}\left(X_k, Z\right)(k \in I)$ also solve the above universal property. In other words, if $Y \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $g_k \in \operatorname{Hom}\left(X_k, Y\right)(k \in I)$ then there exists a unique $g \in \operatorname{Hom}(Z, Y)$ such that $g \circ i_k=g_k$ for all $k \in I$. I want to show that there exists an isomorphism $\varphi: \bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i \stackrel{\sim}{\longrightarrow} Z$ such that $\varphi \circ j_k=i_k(k \in I)$.

My approach to this is the following. In the universal property, I set $Y$ to be this new object $Z$, and I take $f_k\in \operatorname{Hom}\left(X_k, Z\right)$. Then the universal property tells me that there is a unique $f\in \operatorname{Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i, Z\right)$ such that $f \circ j_k=f_k$ for all $k \in I$. Next, I use the fact that $Z$ also solves the universal property to get a unique $g\in \operatorname{Hom}\left(Z,\bigoplus_{i \in I} X_i\right)$ such that $g\circ i_k=g_k$. Now I have to show that $f=g^{-1}$. But I don't know how to conclude this. Can someone help me?

Also, I have another question. At the beginning of my argument I am using that I can take $f_k\in \operatorname{Hom}\left(X_k, Z\right)$. How can I be sure that such homomorphism exists? Is it possible that such hom set is actually empty?

Answer (score 1):

The argument holds more generally:

Limits and colimits, if they exist, are always unique up to unique isomorphism. Suppose $F:I\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is a diagram in $\mathcal{C}$ and let $(C\in \mathcal{C}, f_i: F(i) \rightarrow C)$ and $(C'\in \mathcal{C}, f_i': F(i) \rightarrow C')$ both colimits of $F$. We want to show that there exists a unique $\psi: C \cong C'$ isomorphism compatible with the diagram, i.e. $\psi \circ f_i = f_i'$ for all $i \in I$.

By the universal property of $C$ there exists a unique morphism $g:C\rightarrow C'$ such that $g\circ f_i = f_i'$. Similarly, by the universal property of $C'$ there exists a unique homomorphism $\tilde{g}: C'\rightarrow C$ such that $\tilde{g}\circ f_i' = f_i$. In particular, we have that $\tilde{g}\circ g \circ f_i = f_i$ but also trivially $\operatorname{id}_C \circ f_i = f_i$. By the universal property on $C$ (uniqueness of such solutions) we get $\tilde{g}\circ g = \operatorname{id}_C$. Similarly, repeating the argument we get $g\circ \tilde{g} = \operatorname{id}_{C'}$ which completes the proof our claim.

How this applies to your case: In your case you are considering direct sums in a (pre)-additive category, which you describe as finite coproducts $X_i \rightarrow \bigoplus_k X_k$. You correctly find maps $g$ and $\tilde{g}$ and the last step you are missing is using uqiqueness to show that they are inverses.

To your last question: Since your categories are at least pre-additive and hence $\operatorname{Hom}$-spaces are abelian groups, you always have at least the zero morphism.

Answer (score 0):

The slogan is: *universal properties define objects uniquely up to unique isomorphism.*

Here is a quick way to prove this for the current observation. You will see that all forms are just variations, where one uses a different (auxiliary) category $\mathcal{C}$.

The lemma is also clarifying in that it abstracts all the complexity that you are currently in away (preaddtive, additive, ...).

Since you are familiar with a 0 object you know what an initial object in a Category $\mathcal{C}$ is. Let me repeat to fix notation:

#### Definition

An object $\emptyset$ in a category $\mathcal{C}$  is an object such that for every object $C$ there exists a unique morphism $\emptyset \rightarrow C$

#### Lemma 1

If $\emptyset$ is an initial object, then the only morphism $\emptyset \rightarrow \emptyset$ is the identity.

#### Proof of Lemma 1:

By the definition of a category an identity morphism for $\emptyset$ must exist, by uniqueness there can be no other morphism. $\square$

#### Lemma

If $\emptyset_1$ and $\emptyset_2$ are both initial objects, then there exists a unique isomorphism $\emptyset_1 \simeq \emptyset_2$

#### Proof of Lemma 2:

By assumption on $\emptyset_1$ there exists a unique morphism $$\emptyset_1 \rightarrow \emptyset_2$$
In exactly the same way, by assumption on $\emptyset_2$ there exists a unique morphism "in the other direction" $$\emptyset_2 \rightarrow \emptyset_1$$
Taking composites
$$\emptyset_1 \rightarrow \emptyset_2 \rightarrow \emptyset_1$$
produces an arrow from an initial object to itself, which must be the identity. Analogously in the other direction. $\square$

Now back to your situation:

#### Corollary

Direct sums are unique up to unique isomorphism.

#### Proof of Corollary:

Consider the category whose objects are pairs consisting of an object $Y$ of $\mathcal{C}$ together with a set of maps $\{ f_i : X_i \rightarrow Y\}_{i \in I}$ from the $X_i$ to $Y$ indexed over $I$:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
    X_i @>{f_i}>> Y 
\end{CD}$$

A morphism between two such objects is a map $Y \rightarrow Y'$ such that for all $i \in I$ the following triangle commutes:

$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X_i @>f_i>> Y\\ @.     {_{\rlap{\ f_i'}}\style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(30deg)}{{\xrightarrow[\rule{4em}{0em}]{}}}} @VVV\\  @. Y' \end{CD}$$

A direct sum, is now simply an initial object in that category. $\square$

This is the category of cocones under the given diagram, which you can find in any textbook on category theory. If you wish you can think of these objects as "pre- direct sums", since we have no assumption on uniqueness.